# The "reader" monad

Tags: haskell, monads

OK, so the writer monad allows you to write stuff to [usually] some kind of container, and get that container back at the end. In most implementations, the "container" can actually be any monoid.

Now, there is also a "reader" monad. This, *you might think*, would offer the dual operation - incrementally reading from some kind of container, one item at a time. In fact, this is not the functionality that the usual reader monad provides. (Instead, it merely offers easy access to a semi-global constant.)

To actually write a monad which *is* dual to the usual writer monad, we would need some kind of structure which is dual to a monoid.

1. Does anybody have any idea what this dual structure might be?
2. Has anybody written this monad? Is there a well-known name for it?

Comment: Wouldn't the dual of the writer monad be the cowriter comonad? (Just kidding, I don't really understand what you imagine. Perhaps a `State` consuming a stream?)

Comment: @DanielFischer It sounds crazy enough that it might even be correct...

Comment: The second question makes me think of the infinitude of stream processing libraries that people come up with (Iteratee, pipes, conduits, etc)

Comment: The "reader" monad is often called the environment monad (I think the latter name might actually predate the former - see David Espinosa's thesis in the mid-nineties for an early reference), so expecting reader to be a "dual" of writer might be expecting too much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what the dual of a monoid should be, but thinking of dual (probably incorrectly) as the opposite of something (simply on the basis that a Comonad is the dual of a Monad, and has all the same operations but the opposite way round). Rather than basing it on `mappend` and `mempty` I would base it on:

```
fold :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => f m -> m
```

If we specialise f to a list here, we get:

```
fold :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
```

This seems to me to contain all of the monoid class, in particular.

```
mempty == fold []
mappend x y == fold [x, y]
```

So, then I guess the dual of this different monoid class would be:

```
unfold :: (Comonoid m) => m -> [m]
```

This is a lot like the monoid factorial class that I have seen on hackage [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monoid-subclasses/0.1/doc/html/Data-Monoid-Factorial.html).

So on this basis, I think the 'reader' monad you describe would be a [supply monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-supply/0.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Supply.html). The supply monad is effectively a state transformer of a list of values, so that at any point we can choose to be supplied with an item from the list. In this case, the list would be the result of unfold.supply monad

I should stress, I am no Haskell expert, nor an expert theoretician. But this is what your description made me think of.

Comment: I'm not sure about the comonoid stuff, but the supply monad _does_ look very much like what I had in mind.

Answer (score 34):

The dual of a monoid is a comonoid.  Recall that a monoid is defined as (something isomorphic to)

```
 class Monoid m where
    create :: () -> m
    combine :: (m,m) -> m
```

with these laws

```
 combine (create (),x) = x
 combine (x,create ()) = x
 combine (combine (x,y),z) = combine (x,combine (y,z))
```

thus

```
 class Comonoid m where
    delete :: m -> ()
    split :: m -> (m,m)
```

some standard operations are needed

```
 first :: (a -> b) -> (a,c) -> (b,c)
 second :: (c -> d) -> (a,c) -> (a,d)

 idL :: ((),x) -> x
 idR :: (x,()) -> x

 assoc :: ((x,y),z) -> (x,(y,z))
```

with laws like

```
idL $ first delete $ (split x) = x
idR $ second delete $ (split x) = x
assoc $ first split (split x) = second split (split x)
```

This typeclass looks weird for a reason.  It has an instance

```
instance Comonoid m where
   split x = (x,x)
   delete x = ()
```

in Haskell, this is the *only* instance.  We can recast reader as the exact dual of writer, but since there is only one instance for comonoid, we get something isomorphic to the standard reader type.

Having all types be comonoids is what makes the category "Cartesian" in "Cartesian Closed Category."  "Monoidal Closed Categories" are like CCCs but without this property, and are related to substructural type systems.  Part of the appeal of linear logic is the increased symmetry that this is an example of.  While, having substructural types allows you to define comonoids with more interesting properties (supporting things like resource management).  In fact, this provides a framework for understand the role of copy constructors and destructors in C++ (although C++ does not enforce the important properties because of the existence of pointers).

EDIT: Reader from comonoids

```
newtype Reader r x = Reader {runReader :: r -> x}
forget :: Comonoid m => (m,a) -> a
forget = idL . first delete

instance Comonoid r => Monad (Reader r) where
   return x = Reader $ \r -> forget (r,x)
   m >>= f = \r -> let (r1,r2) = split r in runReader (f (runReader m r1)) r2

ask :: Comonoid r => Reader r r
ask = Reader id
```

note that in the above code every variable is used exactly once after binding (so these would all type with linear types).  The monad law proofs are trivial, and only require the comonoid laws to work.  Hence, `Reader` really is dual to `Writer`.

Comment: Surely that's not the only possible instance of comonoid? How about: `instance Comonoid [a] where { delete = const () ; split [] = ([], []) ; split (x:xs) = ([x], xs) }`

Comment: @DarkOtter: That violates all three laws. The first law says that `idL . first delete $ split (x:xs)` must equal `x:xs`, but `idL . first delete $ split (x:xs) = idL $ first delete ([x],xs) = idL ((),xs) = xs ≠ x:xs`. Similarly, `idR . second delete $ split (x:xs) = idR $ second delete ([x],xs) = idR ([x],()) = [x] ≠ x:xs`; and `assoc . first split $ split (x:y:zs) = assoc $ first split ([x],y:zs) = assoc (([x],[]),y:zs) = ([x],([],y:zs))`, but `second split (split x:y:zs) = second split ([x],y:zs) = ([x],([y],zs)) ≠ ([x],([],y:zs))`. (Sorry for the formatting, but comments can't do better.)

Comment: @DarkOtter assuming totality: `delete` must be `const ()` right?  So then we can show that `fst . split = id` and `snd . split = id` by the laws.  This leads to the conclusion that we have only the one instance.  If the language were not pure we might have more interesting ones.

Comment: @PhilipJF Alternatively, you could generalize the signature of the `Comonoid` class to use morphisms other than Haskell functions, i.e.: `delete :: C m ()` and `split :: C m (m, m)`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez sure, and that lets you do interesting things, you then have to build the reader monad in what ever category you are working with instead of Hask.  A comonoid is just a monoid in the opposite category, so we could just define a single monoid class and be done.

Answer (score 3):

Supply is based on State, which makes it suboptimal for some applications.  For example, we might want to make an infinite tree of supplied values (e.g. randoms):

```
tree :: (Something r) => Supply r (Tree r)
tree = Branch <$> supply <*> sequenceA [tree, tree]
```

But since Supply is based on State, all the labels will be bottom except for the ones one the leftmost path down the tree.

You need something splittable (like in @PhillipJF's `Comonoid`).  But there is a problem if you try to make this into a Monad:

```
newtype Supply r a = Supply { runSupply :: r -> a }

instance (Splittable r) => Monad (Supply r) where
    return = Supply . const
    Supply m >>= f = Supply $ \r ->
        let (r',r'') = split r in
        runSupply (f (m r')) r''
```

Because the monad laws require `f >>= return = f`, so that means that `r'' = r` in the definition of `(>>=)`.. But, the monad laws also require that `return x >>= f = f x`, so `r' = r` as well.  Thus, for `Supply` to be a monad, `split x = (x,x)`, and thus you've got the regular old `Reader` back again.

A lot of monads that are used in Haskell aren't real monads -- i.e. they only satisfy the laws *up to some equivalence relation*.  E.g. many nondeterminism monads will give results in a different order if you transform according to the laws.  But that's okay, that's still monad enough if you're just wondering *whether* a particular element appears in the list of outputs, rather than *where*.

If you allow `Supply` to be a monad up to some equivalence relation, then you can get nontrivial splits.   E.g. [value-supply](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply-0.6) will construct splittable entities which will dole out unique labels from a list in an unspecified order (using `unsafe*` magic) -- so a supply monad of value supply would be a monad up to permutation of labels.  This is all that is needed for many applications.  And, in fact, there is a function

```
runSupply :: (forall r. Eq r => Supply r a) -> a
```

which abstracts over this equivalence relation to give a well-defined pure interface, because the only thing it allows you to do to labels is to see if they are equal, and that doesn't change if you permute them.  If this `runSupply` is the only observation you allow on `Supply`, then `Supply` on a supply of unique labels is a real monad.

Comment: many "monads" are not even monads up to equivalence, but only up to an ordering relation!  That is, you have to rewrite the laws in terms of some "less than or equal to" operator.  Many, like some versions of state, were real monads until we introduced `seq` which broke essentially all the monads.  Even `Id` is probably not a monad because `(.)` and `id` don't form a category.  I think that the correct theoretical thing is probably to reformulate all the laws in terms of 2-categories, and use 2-cells in place of equalities.