# Is there a name for this higher-level "bi" version of distribute in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, traversable, distributive

I have a [`Bitraversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html#v:bisequence) called `t` that supports this operation:

```hs
someName :: Monad m => (t (m a) (m b) -> c) -> m (t a b) -> c
```

In other words, it's possible to take a function that accepts two monads packaged into the bitraversable and turn it into a mapping that accepts a single monad containing a bitraversable without the monad layer. This is something like a bitraversable and higher-level version of [`distribute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute); the type signature is similar to this:

```hs
\f -> \x -> f (distribute x)
  :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => (g (f a) -> c) -> f (g a) -> c
```

My questions:

1. Is there a standard name for this "higher-level" version of `distribute` that works on functions that accept distributives rather than distributives themselves?
2. Is there a name for the bitraversable version?
3. Does it work with every bitraversable/functor/monad/whatever, or are there restrictions?

Comment: To answer 1: your signature is just a continuation passing style (CPS) version of `m (t a b) -> t (m a) (m b)`.

Comment: Agreed, but you can also say that of `traverse` versus `sequenceA`, right? My question is whether there is a pair of names like this.

Comment: No, traverse is not a CPS conversion of sequence. If the type in my previous comment is like sequence /distribute then traverse/collect would be like `(a -> t b c) -> m a -> t (m b) (m c)`.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Noughtmare, your "higher level" functions `someName` and `distribute` are just written in continuation passing style.  These generally aren't worth additional names, because they are just right function compositions:

```
highLevelDistribute = (. distribute)
```

Practically speaking, anywhere you want to call `highLevelDistribute` on an argument:

```
highLevelDistribute f
```

this expression is equivalent to:

```
f . distribute
```

and even if you're using `highLevelDistribute` as a first-class value, it's just not that hard to write and understand the section `(. distribute)`.

Note that `traverse` and `sequenceA` are a little different, since we have:

```
sequenceA = traverse id
```

You could make an argument that this difference doesn't really warrant separate names either, but that's an argument for another day.

Getting back to `someName`, it's a CPS version of:

```
someOtherName :: m (t a b) -> t (m a) (m b)
```

which looks like a bifunctor analogue of `distribute`:

```
distribute :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
```

So, I'd suggest inventing a `Bidistributive` to reflect this, and `someOtherName` becomes `bidistribute`:

```
class Bifunctor g => Bidistributive g where
  {-# MINIMAL bidistribute | bicollect #-}
  bidistribute :: Functor f => f (g a b) -> g (f a) (f b)
  bidistribute = bicollect id
  bicollect :: Functor f  => (a -> g b c) -> f a -> g (f b) (f c)
  bicollect f = bidistribute . fmap f
```

Again, your "higher level" `someName` is just right-composition:

```
someName = (. bidistribute)
```

Reasonable laws for a `Bidistributive` would probably include the following.  I'm not sure if these are sufficiently general and/or exhaustive:

```
-- naturality
bimap (fmap f) (fmap g) . bidistribute = bidistribute . fmap (bimap f g)

-- identity
bidistribute . Identity = bimap Identity Identity

-- composition
bimap Compose Compose . bidistribute . fmap bidistribute = bidistribute . Compose
```

For your question #3, not all `Bitraversable`s are `Bidistributive`, for much the same reason that not all `Traversable`s are `Distributive`.  A `Distributive` allows you to "expose structure" under an arbitrary functor.  So, for example, there's no `Distributive` instance for lists, because if there was, you could call:

```
distribute :: IO [a] -> [IO a]
```

which would allow you to determine if a list returned by an IO action was empty or not, without executing the IO action.

Similarly, `Either` is `Bitraversable`, but it can't be `Bidistributive`, because if it was, you'd be able to use:

```
bidistribute :: IO (Either a b) -> Either (IO a) (IO b)
```

to determine if the IO action returned a `Left` or `Right` without having to execute the IO action.

One interesting thing about `bidistribute` is that the "other functor" can be any `Functor`; it doesn't need to be an `Applicative`.  So, just as we have:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
distribute :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
```

we have:

```
bisequence :: (Bitraversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) (f b) -> f (t a b)
bidistribute :: (Bidistributive g, Functor f) => f (g a b) -> g (f a) (f b)
```

Intuitively, sequencing needs the power of an applicative functor `f` to be able to "build" the `f (t a)` from a traversal of its functorial `f a` "parts", while distribution only needs to take the `f (g a)` apart.  In practical terms, this means that sequencing typically looks like this:

```
-- specialized to t ~ []
sequenceA :: [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA (f:fs) = (:) <$> f <*> fs  -- need applicative operations
```

while distribution typically looks like this:

```
-- specialized to g ~ (->) r
distribute :: f (r -> a) -> (r -> f a)
distribute f r = fmap ($ r) f  -- only need fmap
```

(Technically, according to the documentation for [`Data.Distributive`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.1/distributive-0.6.2.1/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute), the `Distributive` class only requires a `Functor` rather than some coapplicative class because of the lack of non-trivial comonoids in Haskell.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419213/7203016).)